# Куда прописать в AppDelegate?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Нубский вопрос:/
У меня в AppDelegate в нескольких методах используется:

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

И каждый раз в новом методе приходится его прописывать заново.
Вопрос: куда его записать, чтобы каждый раз не приписывать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults;
}
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
+ (void)initialize
{
    userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
}
...
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо:)
Только небольшая поправка: у меня прокатило с `-(void)initialize`